# JSON if value is not undefined, do something

Tags: php, jquery, json

Easy points for someone willing to help a beginner. Using JQuery Form and Validation Plugins to submit a form with PHP and create a MySQL record if certain criteria are met. I'm returning the response as JSON and I want the form to slideUp if server-side validation shows OK, or prepend an error message to the div containing the form and leave the form in place if there are errors. I've gotten valid JSON responses to echo back using:

```
<?php

$errors = array();
$reqs = array('userName', 'Pwd', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'cellPhone', 'homePhone', 'role');
foreach($reqs as $req) {
    if((!isset($_POST[$req])) || (empty($_POST[$req]))) {
            $newerr = array('response' => "The field " . $req . " is required.");
            array_merge(array($errors), array($newerr));
            echo json_encode($newerr);
    }
}

if(is_null($errors)) {
    $auser = new User();
    $hshd = sha1($_POST['Pwd']);
    $auser->userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $auser->hshdPwd = $hshd;
    $auser->firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $auser->lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $auser->email = $_POST['email'];
    $auser->cellPhone = $_POST['cellPhone'];
    $auser->homePhone = $_POST['homePhone'];
    if(!is_null($_POST['school'])) {
    $auser->school = $_POST['school'];
    } else {
        $auser->school = "0";   
    }
    $auser->prelim_role = $_POST['role'];
    $auser->approved = $_POST['approved'];
    if($auser->create()) {
        $abc = array('response'=>"Request successfully submitted. Your account must be configured before you can access the user panel. Please watch for an email confirming your registration and configuration.");
    } else { 
        $abc = array('response'=>"An unknown error occurred. Please send an email to info@aSite.com describing the error event.");
    }
    echo json_encode($abc);
}

?>
```

And the pertinent portion of the JS:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

$("#frmPrntRgstr").ajaxSubmit({
                                                        dataType: 'json',
                                                        success:    processJson,
                                                        })
                            }
});
function processJson(data) { 
        $("#frmPrntRgstr").slideUp("normal", function() {
            $("#frmPrntRgstrRspns").append(data.response).slideDown("normal");
        })
        }
});
```

But with this setup, both the errors and success messages have a key of `'response'` in the JSON Object. The form will slide up whether or not there are errors. I'm thinking of something analogous to `if(array_key_exists)` in PHP. So `if(array_key_exists('errors', $response))` then just prepend, but `if(array_key_exists('success', $response))` append and slide up. Only in JSON.

**EDIT:**

This seems to be working for now. Thanks to Marc B and citizen conn. Please let me know if there are obvious issues or limitations with this structure.

```
<?php  header("Content-type: application/json"); ?>

<?php

$errors = array();

$reqs = array('userName', 'Pwd', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'cellPhone', 'homePhone', 'role');
foreach($reqs as $req) {
    if((!isset($_POST[$req])) || (empty($_POST[$req]))) {
            $newerr = array("error" => "The field " . $req . " is required.");
            $errors[] = $newerr;
    }
}

if(!empty($errors)) {
echo json_encode($errors, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
} else {
    $auser = new User();
    $hshd = sha1($_POST['Pwd']);
    $auser->userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $auser->hshdPwd = $hshd;
    $auser->firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $auser->lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $auser->email = $_POST['email'];
    $auser->cellPhone = $_POST['cellPhone'];
    $auser->homePhone = $_POST['homePhone'];
    if(!is_null($_POST['school'])) {
    $auser->school = $_POST['school'];
    } else {
        $auser->school = "0";   
    }
    $auser->prelim_role = $_POST['role'];
    $auser->approved = $_POST['approved'];
    if($auser->create()) {
        $success = array('response'=>"Request successfully submitted. Your account must be configured before you can access the user panel. Please watch for an email confirming your registration and configuration.");
        echo json_encode($success);
    } else { 
        $failure = array('error'=>"An unknown error occurred. Please send an email to info@aSite.com describing the error event.");
        echo json_encode($failure);
    }

}

?>
```

With the JS callback:

```
function processJson(data) {
    if(data.response) {
        $("#frmPrntRgstr").slideUp("normal", function() {
            $("#frmPrntRgstrRspns").append(data.response).slideDown("normal");
        })
    } else {
        $("#frmPrntRgstr").prepend(data[0].error);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I don't get it : why don't you modify the PHP ? add a key-value like : 'error' => true/false and then check it in the callback

Comment: Your error handling output is incorrect. A JSON response should be a SINGLE json data structure. Your "is required" message will output multiple SEPARATE json structures.

Comment: @marc B I'm aware, I want the function to end and the response to be sent back to client on any error. @Cystack I've used an error array to catch the errors, and can get a JSON response as {"error" : "The field fieldName is required." } My issue is checking in Javascript if the array key `error` exists, and creating a different callback reaction based on the error existing. php would be `if(array_key_exists('error', $response)) { echo "You got errors"; } else { echo "You got no errors"; }` but I don't know how to achieve something similar using a JSON Object.

Comment: @thegumba: that's fine, but only your first error message will be processed by the browser, and the other subsequent strings ignored or treated as an error.

Comment: @Marc B I'm OK with only the first error message getting processed. Right now Firebug shows the only response as the first error. But after a JSON object with `{"error":"the field fieldName is required}` has been sent back, if I correct the field and I reissue the request, I'm getting no response from the server. Is there any way to reset the arrays and/or JSON Objects so that the form will process with the new Request data?

Comment: json is just a data structure. you could simply push each error message onto an array, THEN encode that array and send it over. that way you could show ALL the errors, rather than forcing the user to correct them one at a time (which is horribly user unfriendly).

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this right now, having some trouble. `$errors = array(); if($error_occurs) { $errors[] = $the_error; } if(!empty($errors)) { echo json_encode($errors); } else { submit the form; json_encode($response); }` With two shots at this structure, I'm either getting a "[]" response or a success response from the server. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're expecting JSON you should use `$.getJSON`

```
function processJson(data) { 
    if(!data.response.errors){
        $("#frmPrntRgstr").slideUp("normal", function() {
          $("#frmPrntRgstrRspns").append(data.response).slideDown("normal");
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Does the `dataType: 'json'` in the Form plugin take place of `$.getJSON`? Should this complete the helpful addition you provided above?, `if(!data.response.errors) { $("frmPrntRgstr").slideUp("normal", function() { $("#frmPrntRgstrRspns").append(data.response).slideDown("normal"); }) } else { $("frmPrntRgstr").prepend(data.response.errors) } });`

Comment: Yeah, precisely, on both accounts.

Comment: This works the first time through. But if the initial submission has an error, the first server response is `{"error":"The field fieldName is required"}`. After this error is corrected, there is no server response? Is there anyway to clear the JSON and/or PHP results so that the file handling the submission and JSON will start over clean?

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like this:

```
(typeof data.response == "undefined")
```

If you wish catch the error, use this:

```
    ("#frmPrntRgstr").ajaxSubmit({
                                                        dataType: 'json',
                                                        success:    processJson,
                                                        error: catchError
                                                        })
                            }
})

function catchError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
}
function processJson(data) { 
        $("#frmPrntRgstr").slideUp("normal", function() {
            $("#frmPrntRgstrRspns").append(data.response).slideDown("normal");
        })
        }
});
```